# How do I uploading csv file into Oracle

Tags: oracle, csv

When trying to load csv file into Oracle table through ODI, ODI is not able to fetch the data from csv file. The csv file format is an issue here with the data in a single line. But when we are opening the csv file through excel and then saving it as csv the format is changing and the data is getting arranged properly and then we are able to import it through ODI.
Problem is we need to import the original csv file whatever format it is. Is there a possibility of doing the same?

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL Loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ)** will be the first thing that has came to my mind. I use this a lot.

**[SQL Developer](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/08/how-to-import-from-excel-to-a-new-oracle-table-with-sql-developer/)** will be a better option if you dont want to work with command line utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try using External Tables...you can configure how the CSV should be read in the EXTERNAL TABLE configuration